# In Django, how to find a term that is part of a string instead of containing that string?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, django

For example, there are three rows under two fields in my table like this

```
id name
-------
1  brown cat
2  black dog
3  person
```

And here comes a string, or a sentence: `A brown cat jumps over a person`, how can I use this string to get the first row and third row, which is part of this sentence? As I understand, `__contains`  and `__regex` can only search the terms which contains a target string but will not work if the term is part of the target string.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query will do:

```
>>> sentence = 'A brown cat jumps over a person'
>>> MyModel.objects.extra(where={"%s like CONCAT('%%', `name` ,'%%')"}, 
...                       params=[sentence]).values()
[{'id': 1L, 'name': u'brown cat'}, {'id': 3L, 'name': u'person'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

sentence = 'A brown cat jumps over a person'
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(myfield__icontains=word) for word in sentence.split())))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think a sentence like `This cat is not brown` will also extract the first row.. Is that true?

Comment: Yes.. That is because of the `operator.or_` Use `operator.and_` if you want to do an `and`

Comment: what do you mean by first and third row again ? My answer was just a direction. Not the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the Django ORM, but it's definitely doable with raw SQL. Here's a working query:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE 'A brown cat jumps over a person'
      LIKE '%' || name || '%'
```

The trick is to use the column as the search phrase. This should be reasonably database independent. You could use a QuerySet's [extra method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to limit the use of raw SQL to a minimum.